# Merge slid-in box function and another function

Tags: jquery, hide, html

hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

I have been asked to create a small slide in feature that when the user scrolls down the page, the box appears with the content:

'Find out more: *field with email address box/* SUBMIT->'

There will also be a small icon which the users can close this box if they dont want it there.

Now i have all the functionality working for the box to show on scrolling:

```
    /**************************
    *
    * email function
    *
    **************************/
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            jQuery('#enquiry_submit form').stop().animate({ left: '0' });
        } else {
            jQuery('#enquiry_submit form').stop().animate({ left: '-25%' });
        }
    });
});
```

!!EDIT!!

To make it not show on another page when the user clicks onto another page i was advised below to use cookies. I found a great working solution tested:
http://jsfiddle.net/FcFW2/1/

Now i am stuck to merge these two functions together as when trying the css styling and two functions together just make the box hide all the time.

I am a novice user with jQuery so i understand the basics and how to implement basic functions but in this case hit a wall.

Any guidance would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to stay closed on subsequent pages - the only way I can see this working is by setting a cookie when you close the div.

Then, in your expand method, check for the presence of that cookie, and if it's there, just don't open the div.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i'm new to this so will research this method and let you know how i get on.

Comment: @user2212564 here's a great jquery library for manipulating cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Hi guys, found a cookie solution (applied and works). My only issue is to get the scrolling function working with it as when applying the two together they don't work (no errors) and div just hides.

Comment: try putting a duration parameter in your animate method: .animate({ left: '0' }, 1000);

Comment: still no luck, i think its to do with my css as when i put a -200pc left on it thats when it stops showing when i'm trying to animate, it does work though when i do a fadeIn

Comment: is the element you're animated position relative or absolute? if neither of those, the "left" property will have no effect. try "margin-left" if you can't make it relative / absolute.

Comment: I think its the way i'm laying the code, i will start a new question as who answered the cookie solution is the answer so people dont get confused - will link to the new question.